# Is it safe to uninstall evolution-data-server packages on 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, uninstall, evolution

Is it safe to uninstall evolution-data-server package on Ubuntu 20.04? I have noticed that a number of evolution processes (e.g. evolution-alarm-notify) are running.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks for that info. Your command gave me similar results. So I won't do the remove! The reason that I wanted to remove the packages is that I'm frequently being prompted by a popup (initiated by Thunderbird?) to input my password for Google Calendar, even though I've removed my Gmail account (with its data) from it though I haven't deleted the Gmail a/c as I use that a/c for my Android phone's Gmail a/c : interestingly, the popup then asks again presumably due to rejecting my correct password! Any ideas on how to stop this popup appearing or to get the password accepted by the popup?

Comment: `evolution-alarm-notify` isn't supposed to be connected to Thunderbird unless you use some sort of plugin like [Evolution Mirror](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/evolution-mirror/) ... anyway that is a different question that calls for a new post to be properly answered ... Thus, I suggest you consider this question as answered and open a new question about the popups with the info in your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the removal of the package with APTs option `-s` like so:

```
apt remove -s evolution-data-server
```

This way you can see what will exactly happen during a real uninstall.

On my system it shows the following packages to be removed during this process:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-gnome-shell evolution-data-server gdm3 gnome-remote-desktop gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extensions gnome-todo gnome-tweaks ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session
```

That is clearly **unsafe**.